Post filter for response body modification
I have created a post filter which on completion of backend service call, processes the  response. I want to add this response to exchange attribute to be checked in the other post  filters. But it is not able to set it to exchange, also logs added in re write function are not getting displayed.
@Component
public class TestFilterGatewayFilterFactory extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<TestFilterGatewayFilterFactory.Config> implements Ordered {

  public static final int FILTER_ORDER = -1;
  final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestFilterGatewayFilterFactory.class);

  private final ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory modifyResponseBodyFilterFactory;

  @Autowired
  public TestFilterGatewayFilterFactory(ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory modifyResponseBodyFilterFactory) {
    super(Config.class);
    this.modifyResponseBodyFilterFactory = modifyResponseBodyFilterFactory;
  }

  @Override
  public int getOrder() {
    return FILTER_ORDER;
  }

  public static class Config {
    public Config() {
    }
  }

  @Override
  public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
    return (exchange, chain) -> chain.filter(exchange).then(Mono.defer(() -> {
      logger.info("Processing Test Filter");
      final ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config    modifyResponseBodyFilterFactoryConfig = new ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config();

      
      modifyResponseBodyFilterFactoryConfig.setRewriteFunction(String.class, String.class, (cexchange, bodyAsString) -> {
        logger.info("Response Body: {}", bodyAsString);
        try {
          JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(bodyAsString);
         ** cexchange.getAttributes().put("jsoncustomResponse", jsonResponse);
          exchange.getAttributes().put("jsoncustomResponse", jsonResponse);**
          return Mono.just(jsonResponse.toString()); // Return as JSON string
        } catch (JSONException e) {
          logger.error("Failed to parse JSON", e);
          return Mono.just(bodyAsString); // Fallback to original body
        }
      });

      // Set the new content type
      modifyResponseBodyFilterFactoryConfig.setNewContentType("application/json");

      // Create and apply the filter
      GatewayFilter filter = modifyResponseBodyFilterFactory.apply(modifyResponseBodyFilterFactoryConfig);
      return filter.filter(exchange, chain).then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
        JSONObject customResponse = (JSONObject) exchange.getAttributes().get("jsoncustomResponse");
        if (customResponse != null) {
          logger.info("Custom Response: {}", customResponse);
        } else {
          logger.info("No custom response found");
        }
      }));
    }));
  }
} 

